# Expose A Port To Outside World On Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to host a minecraft server on minikube. The server accepts tcp requests on port 25565 but I don't know how to expose it out.

I've tried NodePort, LoadBalancer (just nodeport since minikube dont have a loadbalancer), and port forwarding. None of these worked.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: velocity-deployment
  labels:
    app: velocity
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: velocity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: velocity
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: velocity-container
        image: myimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 25565
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minecraft-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: velocity-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 25565
      targetPort: 25565
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

EDIT: I cannot port-forward for some strange reason. I tried to port forward but it timed out for some reason. Here is the log:

kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/minecraft-service 25565:25565
error: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: You will need to take a look on how to expose this `NodePort` to outside world (outside of your host). It will depend on the driver that you are using by far. If you could let us know the driver then it would be easier to point you to a solution. 

As a quick **workaround** you can run on the server `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/minecraft-service 25565:25565`. In that case your minecraft server will be available on port 25565 outside of your host (assuming there is an access to it).

Comment: What do you mean by driver? Sorry I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube will not be available to the outside world by default, so you must expose it if you want to be able to access it from outside the cluster.

To expose it to external traffic you need to expose using the below command with NodePort as a parameter.

`kubectl expose deployment/velocity-deployment --type="NodePort" --port =25565`

Refer to this [official doc](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes_101/module4/#step-1---create-a-new-service) for more information.

Comment: Does that do anything besides create the NodePort-type Service that's already in the question?

Comment: Even after creating Nodeport, OP needs to expose the port using the Nodeport to accept the outside traffic thats the reason i asked to do this.

Comment: But, the nodeport that I selected is 31000, do I use 25565 in this case or 31000. I want others to connect with myip:25565 though which is connecting to my 25565.

Comment: you can expose using the port 25565 and let me know. As you want others to connect then  you need to [tunnel into Minikube for access](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:%7E:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system).

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about this as I went on a vacation. It is. I am able to expose the service and access it from outside. However, it only works if I use something like this `kubectl expose deployment/velocity-deployment --type="NodePort" --port 25577` to create a service instead of me creating it myself, which is kind of weird. When I try to port forward the service it has no responce and times out; the one created using the `expose` command has no issue and works perfectly.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a smart solution. Thank you very much for your help and I've gone ahead and upvoted + accepted your answer.